# Filter Price now showing on multiple websites using elastic search 6 +

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, elasticsearch, layer

Currently after 2.3.1 magento upgrade I start to use elastic search 6.
On my magento application i have multiple websites and for some reason, except the default website the price filter was not showing at all.
I start to debug this issue and i found a solution.

I will post my solution, because maybe in the future someone will have exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference for="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\Product\FieldProvider\FieldName\Resolver\Price"
            type="Vendor\MOdule\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\Product\FieldProvider\FieldName\Resolver\Price"/>

and Price.php 

class Price extends \Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\FieldMapper\Product\FieldProvider\FieldName\Resolver\Price
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSession
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var StoreManager
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
     */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * Price constructor.
     * @param CustomerSession|null $customerSession
     * @param StoreManager|null $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        CustomerSession $customerSession = null,
        StoreManager $storeManager = null
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(StoreManager::class);
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(CustomerSession::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getFieldName(AttributeAdapter $attribute, $context = []): ?string
    {
        if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() === 'price') {
            $path = $this->_request->getPathInfo();
            $customerGroupId = !empty($context['customerGroupId'])
                ? $context['customerGroupId']
                : $this->customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
            $websiteId = !empty($context['websiteId'])
                ? $context['websiteId']
                : $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();

            if ($path) {
                $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
                return 'price_' . $customerGroupId . '_' . $storeId;
            } else {
                return 'price_' . $customerGroupId . '_' . $websiteId;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```